# Error handling - no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am trying to handle exceptions using ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice, have a transformer for a fail channel,

```
<int:transformer input-channel="afterFailureChannel" output-channel="validateOutputChannel" ref="testExceptionTransformer" method="handleLockServiceResponse"/>
```

In testExceptionTransformer, I am forming user defined exception and sending it in http response entity which I want to send as a rest api response, Even though transformer has outputChannel, application throws

```
org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:452) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.13.jar:5.5.13]
```

Could you please help?

Edit:

Transformer looks like this,

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleLockServiceResponse(Message<MessagingException> message) throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    LOGGER.error(message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().toString());
        LOGGER.error(message.getPayload().getCause().toString());

        try {
            Throwable exception = message.getPayload().getCause();
            if (exception.getCause() instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
                throw new handleValidationException(exception.getCause().getMessage());
            }
        }catch(handleValidationException ex){
            return adapterErrorHandler.handleCustomValidationException(ex);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed doesn't fail in your transformer since you have that `output-channel` it fails in the initial gateway when it tries to correlate the reply message into a `TemporaryReplyChannel` from headers. We need to see what your transformer does, but the rule of thumb is if you return a `Message` from the transformer, you have to coyp headers from request message. However with an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and its `failureChannel` it is a bit tricky.

The logic there is like this:

```
    if (evalResult != null && this.failureChannel != null) {
        MessagingException messagingException =
                new MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException(message, "Handler Failed",
                        unwrapThrowableIfNecessary(exception), evalResult);
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(messagingException);
        this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, errorMessage);
    }
```

It becomes obvious that `ErrorMessage` doesn't have a request message headers. So, you need to extract them from that exception via `getFailedMessage()` and that's the one is sent to your service instrumented with that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

We probably need to improve the doc on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

**UPDATE**

So, now you return a `ResponseEntity` from your transformer method and headers for the reply message is copied from that `ErrorMessage` we send from the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. To preserve original message headers in the reply message you must do something like this:

```
public Message<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleLockServiceResponse(Message<MessagingException> message) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
LOGGER.error(message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().toString());
    LOGGER.error(message.getPayload().getCause().toString());

    try {
        Throwable exception = message.getPayload().getCause();
        if (exception.getCause() instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
            throw new handleValidationException(exception.getCause().getMessage());
        }
    }catch(handleValidationException ex){
        response = adapterErrorHandler.handleCustomValidationException(ex);
    }
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(response).copyHeaders(message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders()).build();
}
```

Comment: I am new to integration so having difficulty figuring out your comment! I have simple transformer which I added as a part of the question. can you please take a look and suggest how can I extract and pass on request headers?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, that fixed the issue though its still throwing HttpClientErrorException instead of custom exception(handleValidationException). It might be something wrong with how the ResponseEntity is working! I tried with following but still same issue, MessageBuilder.withPayload(new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(),response.getHeaders(),response.getStatusCode())).copyHeaders(message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders()).build();

Comment: I think this is already a different story in context of how you call this service, what you send as that `ResponseEntity`and what result you got on your HTTP client for this request.